# Where on the Jeep Wrangler TJ can I tap into the oil line?

Tags: oil, jeep, wrangler, by-pass

I would like to install a By-Pass filter on my Jeep TJ (2004).  Where can I put the other end of the tube going into the filter?  I have included a diagram illustrating what I am looking for (where the red circle is) on the Jeep.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the commentary on the diagram?  The implication is that you should tap the oil feed where the current oil pressure sending unit is already doing the same thing.  Is that what you're trying to locate?

Comment: This thread has a reasonable picture of the location in question: http://www.jeepforum.com/forum/f9/oil-pressure-sending-unit-1326986/

Answer (score 2):

It's easier just to buy the filter adapter kit for $50 that way you don't have to tap a return line either.

That's what I did.

But if your cheap sometimes engines have an extra oil feed bung down on the lower part of the engine block near where the oil pump would be just above the oil pan. Don't know if your jeep has one but worth a quick snoop.